# Sidebar won't go to the top in masonry layout

Tags: html, css

I'm building a Tumblr theme and I implemented a masonry grid plugin into it and the sidebar won't align with the content despite that I have it **float: right** in CSS. Here's my layout, http://lt-sushi.tumblr.com/ and here's the code I have so far, http://pastebin.com/yddVLgPq. I've tried a lot of methods to get the sidebar to go to the top but nothing has worked and I'm really frustrated. If anyone can tell me how to fix this, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<aside id="sidebar">` to `<div id="sidebar">`

Comment: I tried changing that to <div id="sidebar"> but it's still not going to the top. Could it be my CSS codes or something?

Comment: Oh I see.. The Masonry plugin positions the blocks absolute and only when they are inside the `<section id="content">` tag. The float right doesn't do anything because it's not inside of the content div.

Try to place `<aside id="sidebar">`...</aside>` within `{/block:Posts}` and `</section>`

Comment: I've got everything taken care of. Thanks.